# CodeFights CheckPalindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

There is a website called *CodeFights*, and they have a challenge which has caused me a little bit of a problem.

**Here is my code:**

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
String[] inputStringArray = inputString.split("");

    String reverseInputString = "";

    for (int x = inputString.length() - 1; x >= 0; x = x - 1) {
        reverseInputString = reverseInputString + inputStringArray[x];
    }

    System.out.println(reverseInputString); // for debugging purposes only 
    System.out.println(inputString); // for debugging purposes only 

    if (reverseInputString == inputString) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**The weird stuff:**

- Let's say that *inputString* equals *aba*.
- Then `System.out.println(reverseInputString);` and `System.out.println(inputString);` are both going to print out *aba*, which is just what I want.
- However, my *if statement* is going to return *false*, and I don't have a single clue why it is always happening.

I mean literally, I've tried everything in my knowledge to debug my humble "application", but nada; it doesn't seem to show any sign of working properly. It might very well be that the solution is quite easy, in which case I apologise for even asking this question, however, I've only been learning **Java** for *3 days*, which is not a long period of time.

I am looking forward to reading your ideas and opinion on this matter.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `if (reverseInputString.equals(inputString)`

Comment: compare strings using oneString.equals(otherString)

Comment: Thank you! WoW, this is really embarrassing. Yeah... Before Java, I had learned some Phyton, and I have thought that double equal signs would work.

Comment: == should only be used to compare primitives. For comparing objects always use .equals()

Comment: @digidude There are some exceptions, but that's a good rule of thumb.